# Arachas decoction mechanics

Tags: the-witcher-3

Has anyone done the theory crafting on the Arachas decoction yet?

*Does it have a maximum encumbrance over which it has no effect? If so, what is it?

*What is the DR per weight? And does it take effect before or after armor value?

*Is armor type a modifier or flat value?

It seems like this decoction is trying to make up for the lower armor value in lighter armor, but by the time you get Mastercrafted Witcher gear, the values are the same. Is this just supposed to be an early game decoction you cant get to till the late 20s?

Comment: I do not know the specifics, but I'll go on a limb and assume that it means that to get the maximum benefit you should be using light armor. Medium armor gets medium benefit, and heavy armor gets a negligible benefit.

Comment: That seems a fairly safe assumption, considering it's explicitly mentioned in the description of the decoction